# Ajax always return "1" after new HTML content code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I implemented my Java Script on changing Form content after clicking on button. Everything works, but each time I replace old HTML with new one ...after content is displayed "1" number.

My Javascript :

```
$(document).on('click','#customButton', function (evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    var requestArray = $(".form_step").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {"action": "testNewsletter", "form_step":requestArray},
        dataType: "",
        success:function(data) {

            $(".current").empty();
            $(".current").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

custom function in `functions.php` :

```
function testNewsletter() {

    $FormId ='';

    If(isset($_POST['form_step'])){
        $FormId = $_POST['form_step'];
    }

    if($FormId == 1){
        echo include ('pages/forms/form-two.php');
        //echo 'AHOJ';
    }

    else if($FormId == 2){
        echo include ('pages/forms/form-three.php'); 
    }

    else {
        echo include ('pages/forms/form-four.php');
    }

    wp_die();

}
```

HTML I replaced with new HTML:

```
<form  method="post" class="newsletter">
    <div class="current">
        <div class="fce-newsletter-form">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                    <h2 class="mb-half"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_title')?></h2>
                    <p class="mb-2 lead">Mit unserem Newsletter erhalten Sie monatlich Informationen rund um das Urlaubsland Österreich und eine Auswahl exklusiver Angebote und Gutscheine!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="testFormChange">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="custom-input-newsletter" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail Adresse *" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="button" class="fce-newsletter-form-button btn btn-block btn-primary" id="customButton" value="Weiter">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="step1" name="step">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-note">mit * gekennzeichnete Felder bitte ausfüllen.</p>
                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-error-message"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_step" class="form_step" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Each new HTML data has similar content to first HTML, for example:

```
<div class="fce-newsletter-form">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
            <h2 class="mb-half"><?php the_sub_field('form_four_title')?></h2>
            <p class="mb-2 lead">Vielen Dank für Ihre Anmedung zu unserem Newsletter.
                Sie erhalten in Kürze eine E-Mail mit einem Bestätigungslink.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="link-read-more"> <?php
                            include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/img/svg/icon_arrow.svg';
                            ?>
                            Zum Newsletterarchiv
                        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I returned string in echo... number is not showed, but when I returned folder... each time number will be appears. Someone does have some advice for me, please?

Comment: Remove the `echo` from your `include`

Comment: I thought, that I need to echo new HTML content. Good advice. thank you

Comment: I used echo of data on success function already, but it returns only HTML code, not folder... now I realized that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` goes to html mode automatically and returns a `boolean` indicating success if the included file exists. Since your file is mostly markup it outputs it directly. So remove the `echo` from the `include statement` to fix this.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-124) (skip to after the Warning)